# When Servlet Destroy the Value of Declared Variable

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I declare List in Servlet for temporary hold the data, before inserting database:

```
List poList= new ArrayList();
```

First time user enter the data,and then after 10-15 or 30-45 minutes he enter more data.

Does old data is available in Servlet or Servlet Destroy the all previous entered data after prescribed time ?

Comment: Where in the servlet is `poList` declared?  Is it a local variable within a method or is it a member variable of your servlet class?

Comment: It a member variable of my servlet class! @QuantumMechanic

Comment: Learn here how servlets work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/3106909#3106909

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that. There is only one servlet instance for all the users of this webapp. This means that all the users will store data, concurrently, in the same list. The HTTP session is the place where to store data associated to one particular user, and whose lifetime must span several requests.

First request:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("myList", list);
```

Second request:

```
List<Something> myList = (List<Something>) request.getSession().getAttribute("myList);
```

Also note that destroy doesn't matter: destroy is called when the application ends (because the server is stopped, for example).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the data per user, this wont serve your purpose.Add the `poList` to the `HttpSession` as attribute.Manipulate it in your `doPost()`/`service()` method.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If your poList is in a singleton or is declared as an static List, values are keep on your poList.